# Vaadin 23 correctly remove and destroy component

Tags: garbage-collection, vaadin, vaadin23

Right now in order to remove the `ComboBox` element from the `FormLayout` I use the following method:

```
formLayout.getElement().removeChild(locationComboBox.getElement());
```

I still have a validation binder associated with `locationComboBox`. I may remove binding in the following way:

```
binder.removeBinding(locationComboBox);
```

that's works fine. But I'm thinking about the `locationComboBox` ? Is it enough to just remove the component via `removeChild` method, or I should call some additional logic in order to completely destroy the `locationComboBox` element and remove it from the memory? Or this is a task for JVM GC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`formLayout.getElement().removeChild(locationComboBox.getElement())` is [equivalent](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/e5d0493d2b90666d0aa04edf5d5ae7c5e5d7fb1a/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasComponents.java#L126) to `formLayout.remove(locationComboBox)` minus some check that the element is actually a child of the parent.

Both will effectively remove the combo box from the layout, but there may some other hard references to the component (from the binder, or from some listeners) that prevents it from being garbage collected.